Splitting method for PDEs
Splitting methods are widely used for Multiphysics problems. I found a few ODE examples in Advance documentation for NDSolve.
I wonder whether any such methods are available for coupled PDE systems.
A type of system I have in mind, consists of a scalar variable s[x, t], (x – space, t – time) coupled to vector F[x, t] via evolution equations:

Dt[s] + div[u F] = N[s,F],
Dt[F] + B.grad[s] = A[s].F,

where N[s, F] is a nonlinear function of s and F, B is a diagonal matrix, and A[s] is a s-dependend matrix.
A splitting method should fix F to solve (1) for s[x,t] ('x-dependent ODEs'). Then fix s[x,t] and employ LocallyExact for F[x,t] - a family of linear ODEs (1.).

The method of lines basically calls an ODE integration method on a spatial discretization of the PDE that yields a systems of ODEs. So it should be possible. I have not done it, so I don't know if it's easy or not. One might have to do the spatial discretization oneself — how to do that is shown in the documentation for the Method of Lines — so that the splitting can be specified. I do not recall having seen it on site, so I offer these remarks in case you get no other help. I suppose you've seen Splitting

Can you be more specific, say, show us an example solving PDE with splitting method so we can try reproducing the result?

Thanks for comments. I saw documentation on Splitting with simple ODE examples. In my case I guess, a way to procced would be discretize PDE system by the method of lines (`FiniteDifferenceDerivative) and apply Splitting to the resulting ODE systems. If it works will show the result.
